# Singleton Overuse

Tags: c#, winforms, singleton

I was considering using a Singleton pattern in a winforms application that I am working on, but a lot of people seem to think that singletons are evil. I was planning on making a "Main Menu" form which is a singleton. I can't think of any reason that I would want multiple instances of my Main Menu, and it is always going to be the first form that comes up, so I am not concerned with wasting resources if it gets instantiated unnecessarily.

Also, I could see issues arising if there are multiple instances of the Main Menu. For example, if another form has a "Main Menu" button and there are multiple instances of the Main Menu, then the decision of which instance to show seems ambiguous.

Also, if I have another winform which has to look at the state of the program to determine whether there is already an instance of the main menu, then I feel like I am breaking modularity, though I might be wrong.

Should I be avoiding the use of a singleton in this case or would it be better to make the Main Menu static?

I just started using c# a couple days ago, and I haven't really done much with OOP in the last few years, so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

Thanks

Comment: You should be avoiding unneeded global state. Singletons are just one way such state can occur (but apparently that's not as obvious to some people, so they use it while giving lip service to "globals = bad"). A static variable is *also a global*. So please don't take "Singletons are evil" at face value; understand the issues those complaints aim at.

Comment: On that note, I love the article [Singletons are Pathological Liars](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/).

Comment: You may also find [my write-up on the subject](http://jalf.dk/singleton/) worth a read. :)

Comment: Given that you understand the problems around Singletons (which I never found a single case to use), and global objects, you're the only one who can make the decision to use it or not.

Comment: By the way, to contrast the singleton bashing: A corollary of the main problem being global state, a singleton (like other means of global state) is not necessarily bad. It doesn't hurt (at least w.r.t. proliferation of global state) when it just wraps something which is already (or by its very nature) global (say, some process-wide state provided by the OS, like the working directory) and hence doesn't introduce any more state than already exists. But this is not the case here.

Comment: This really belongs on either programmers or code review (if you posted some example code).

Comment: @GregHewgill "When you get your credit card bill, you are out $100 for every time the test runs." That gave me good laugh! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `MainMenu` shown all the time? If not, it would make sense to release the old instance when it's closed and create a new one every time you need to open it. This way other modules won't need to know of its instances, they'll just create one when they need to open it.

Comment: Thanks, that seems so logical. For some reason I had it in my head that I wanted to just hide the menu when I went to another window and then show it again when I wanted to come back, but I'm not really sure where that idea came from.

Comment: Ok, I sort of realize why i didn't do that. I am having trouble closing the main menu when i navigate to another menu. When I put a this.Close() before opening the new winform, the program ends, and when I put this.Close() after opening the new winform, the Main Menu does not close.

Comment: @Eric That's because your main menu is the main form.  It probably just means that it shouldn't be the main form; something else should be.

Answer (score 1):

People like global state. It is apparently easy to understand, and makes sense to us. You don't have to worry about which version you are using because they are all the same.

However global state introduces all kinds of odd errors, so is generally discouraged. C# made many design decisions to make global state harder to miss use. For instance you are allowed static variables only attached to a class that must manage them.

Singletons are another way to get this global state, however they are similar in that they can cause issues. What if one of your screens sets a part of the main menu then transitions to it, not realizing that a background process undid the change, resulting in an odd main menu being displayed?

The other alternative to singletons is to ensure that the variables reach where they are needed. One way of doing that is to keep track of a stack of menus, in fact Android works like this underneath. Every UI gets a set of parents that are above it, that it can switch to if it wants to go back. By ensuring that only your initial boot up process creates the initial main menu screen, you can guarantee only one is created, however all screens can still access it by checking the hierarchy.

Additionally if you are talking about winforms, they already have a hierarchy system built in that you can use to provide this functionality.

Comment: Static variables don't make global state harder to use. It's just a way to namespace global variables.

Comment: @delnan: You can't just create a variable named `numApples` is what I meant by difficult.

Comment: Adding `class Whatever {` before it (and a closing brace at the end) is trivial. Also, since pretty much all code has to be in classes/structs, you always already have a class at hand. Really, the language does not do anything (effective) to prevent global state (of any kind). That's likely because nobody intended it to do that, because (1) as other answers note, everything can be abused, so there's little point in going out of your way to "prevent" bad code, and (2) it's much more effective to encourage good practices instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can abuse almost everything.

A singleton is a way to guarantee that there is only one instance of an object active at any time, and you can synchronize access to it. With a static class you lose that, since the static class can be accessed by anyone at any time, you need to make sure your methods don't do nothing that can be affected by concurrency.

Beyond that, if i'm reading you right, you want a form that would be the parent form to have the only instance of your menu and all other form would be childs of this one. If this is the case then you should check MDI (Multiple Document Interface) in Winforms since this will cover your scenario just right.

Otherwise, what i would do, is simply to define a class for my parent form (the one with the main menu) and have a singleton expose accest to it, and use another base class for all the child forms.